# jQuery Show/Hide multiple galleries

Tags: jquery

I have three galleries on a page and want them to show with simple jQuery show/hide technique.

Gallery works perfect, but maybe there are some more preview galleries to display in the future.

What I have done so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#gallery1').click(function() {
  $('#gallery').hide();
  $('#previewGallery1').show();
});

$('#showGallery1').click(function() {
  $('#gallery').show();
  $('#previewGallery1').hide();
});

$('#gallery2').click(function() {
  $('#gallery').hide();
  $('#previewGallery2').show();
});

$('#showGallery2').click(function() {
  $('#gallery').show();
  $('#previewGallery2').hide();
});

$('#gallery3').click(function() {
  $('#gallery').hide();
  $('#previewGallery3').show();
});

$('#showGallery3').click(function() {
  $('#gallery').show();
  $('#previewGallery3').hide();
});

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/stef75/ah3Lxkdy/

Need some help to add more generic code here :)

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using html data attributes

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("[data-show-gallery]").click(function() { 
    $('[data-gallery-preview]').hide(); // feel free to use a class here insted
    $('[data-gallery='+$(this).attr("data-show-gallery")+']').show();
  });

  $("[data-close-gallery]").click(function() {// feel free to use a class here insted
    $('[data-gallery-preview]').show(); // feel free to use a class here insted
    $('[data-gallery]').hide(); // feel free to use a class here insted
  });

});
```

```css
#gallery {
    background: orange;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .previewImage {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: green;
    height: 250px;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 1%;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .previewGallery {
    margin: 1%;
    background: blue;
  }

  [data-gallery] {
    display: none;
  }

  .previewThumb {
    background: orange;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 1%;
  }
  
a { color: #fff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Above gallery...</div>

<div id="gallery" data-gallery-preview>
  <div class="previewImage" data-show-gallery="1">Preview-Image Gallery 1</div>
  <div class="previewImage" data-show-gallery="2">Preview-Image Gallery 2</div>
  <div class="previewImage" data-show-gallery="3">Preview-Image Gallery 3</div>
</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<div data-gallery="1">
  <div class="previewGallery">
    <h2>Preview-Gallery 1</h2>
    <div class="previewThumb">thumb 1</div>
    <div class="previewThumb">thumb 2</div>
    <div class="previewThumb">thumb 3</div>
    <div class="previewThumb">thumb 4</div>
    <div class="previewThumb">thumb 5</div>
    <div class="previewThumb">thumb 6</div>

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <a href="#" data-close-gallery>&lt;&lt; back</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-gallery="2">
  <div class="previewGallery">
    <h2>Preview-Gallery 2</h2>
    <div class="previewThumb">thumb 1</div>
    <div class="previewThumb">thumb 2</div>
    <div class="previewThumb">thumb 3</div>
    <div class="previewThumb">thumb 4</div>
    <div class="previewThumb">thumb 5</div>
    <div class="previewThumb">thumb 6</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <a href="#" data-close-gallery>&lt;&lt; back</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-gallery="3">
  <div class="previewGallery">
    <h2>Preview-Gallery 3</h2>
    <div class="previewThumb">thumb 1</div>
    <div class="previewThumb">thumb 2</div>
    <div class="previewThumb">thumb 3</div>
    <div class="previewThumb">thumb 4</div>
    <div class="previewThumb">thumb 5</div>
    <div class="previewThumb">thumb 6</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <a href="#" data-close-gallery>&lt;&lt; back</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div>Below gallery...</div>
```

Comment: This is nice and very helpful for me!

Now the BE-Dev will not kill me anymore :)

Many thx!